# Правильно ли управление?

Tags: управление

Профессор международной политики Университета

Правильно ли будет так сказать или надо: профессор по международной политике в Университете?

Comment: профессор по международной политике в Московском университете?

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Если это в России, то профессор кафедры международной политики или профессор-эксперт по международной политике университета... Это должность на кафедре вузов и звание.

Если это перевод с иностранного, то "Профессор международной политики Университета" будет корректно, потому что там профессором является преподаватель отдельных дисциплин, в частности международной политики.

Профессор ПО какой-то дисциплине - это не совсем корректно, лучше "преподаватель по дисциплине "...".

Answer (score 2):

ИЗ ТОЛКОВОГО СЛОВАРЯ: профессор: А) учёное звание, присваиваемое наиболее квалифицированным преподавателям ; лицо, носящее это звание. П. математики. Б) Должность в высшем учебном заведении; лицо, занимающее эту должность. В) О знатоке своего дела. Слыть профессором. Знакомьтесь: главный п. по танцулькам.

В двух первых значениях форма "профессор по" не применяется, а вот в третьем значении используется достаточно широко. Кроме того, область применения этого значения расширяется, и профессора минералогии в разговорной речи вполне допустимо назвать профессором по минералогии.

Примеры

И вот профессор по минералогии, старый еще профессор, он всех еще «господами» звал, говорит: «А это что за минерал, господин Пирамидальный? (А. Битов).

Ты прямо-таки профессор по этой части.

Профессор по экономике рассказывал скучные лекции.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет: университетский профессор по международной политике.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: университетский профессор по международной политике. Иначе получится, что международная политика имеет профессора, что, согласитесь, не логично. Такое сочетание являются переводом с английского, где сохраняется структура предложения языка-оригинала.